# Widget.Holo.TextView.ListSeperator causing crashes in Settings.apk

Tags: android, styles, cyanogenmod

I am making a theme for CyanogenMod 10.1 and I have stumbled upon one problem.

I added this to my styles.xml:

```
<style name="Widget.Holo.TextView.ListSeparator" parent="@android:style/Widget.QuickContactBadge">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/list_divider_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/frameworks_res_list_section_divider_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

Apparently `<item name="android:gravity">center</item>` makes it crash. I tried compiling it with latest frameworks of both CyanogenMod and AOKP, yet some users are still have force closes/crashes in settings.apk.

I have a few logcats that users have provided, but they are mostly useless.

I would really appreciate if someone has an idea how to solve this and make it work for everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some listpreference can't supports the QuickContactBadge together. So what you can do is remove the background...

This is how i fix my FC, so no-no background included. :(

https://github.com/XYAOSP/vendor-tmobile-themes-SnapBlack/commit/5b324cee69f202acb1d62bb9e967cdac29938e82

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to set parent to 'parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.ListSeparator"'. If it doesn't work out, I will try to link my background differently.